# OO Class Design for ATM card

Tags: object-oriented, solid, encapsulation

I have to design a Class for ATM cards with the following attributes:

1. Cardholder Name
2. Card Number
3. Pin

Other than getters and setters, I have a method to validate the pin of the ATM. As per the principle of encapsulation all the methods related to the ATM should be part of the ATM class.

But in case, later we need to change the business logic of the validate method. We shouldn't modify the class as per the Open-Closed principle and extending the class and creating a new class will make me change the instantiation of the ATM class from the complete project.

One way is to have a factory pattern which gives me the ATM object and later when I extend the class I will change the ATM object to the NewATM object.

Now I have the following questions for the problem:

1. Should the validate method be part of the ATM class?
2. Is there any other cleaner way of solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm skeptical of your application of the Open/Closed principle in this context.

Wikipedia [defines the Open Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) as "classes should be open for extension, but closed for modification."  But it also clarifies that statement by saying: *"in other words, classes should allow their behaviour to be **extended** without modifying their source code."*

**Do you have a requirement for your ATM class to be *extensible?***

If you don't have such a requirement, then you shouldn't put code in place that satisfies a requirement that doesn't exist.

Comment: I was curious if to use encapsulation properly should the validatePin method be part of the ATM class?

Comment: That's as good a place as any.

Comment: If you're modeling a modern chip-and-pin card then it is the card that performs verification of the PIN, so I would put the function in the class for the card.